# Why my Matcher.find() evaluates to false?

Tags: java, regex

I have following code:

```
Pattern lPattern = Pattern.compile("^.*THREADINFO.*\\sJ9VMTHREAD:([0123456789xABCDEF]*).*")
Matcher lMatcher = lPattern.matcher("3XMTHREADINFO      \"WebContainer : 14\" J9VMThread:0x0000000085046300, j9thread_t:0x00007FC39C10BDF0, java/lang/Thread:0x000000000B2E08E8, state:B, prio=5")
if(lMatcher.find())
    println lMatcher.group(1)
```

I felt it should print `0x0000000085046300`, but it did not. This regex works perfect in fetching `0x0000000085046300` from the input line as can be seen in online regex tester [here](https://www.regex101.com/r/rT2vC9/1). But then why this Java code fails to print the same? What I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is case-sensitive, thus not picking up `J9VMThread` because it's spelled in all upper-case in your regex. You can prefix your regex with `(?i)` or use `Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)` to turn off case-sensitivity.

Comment: Yes! and please be aware that online regex checkers are **NOT** the same behaviour as in java.

Answer (score 4):

Your regex capturing group is wrong, it matches even strings like `0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x85046300` and it takes a lots of (useless) steps.

In addiction, you didn't specify the case insensitive flag, that's the reason it doesn't match.

You can simplify your regex a lot, in that way

`(?i)J9VMTHREAD:([0-9]+x[0-9A-F]+)`

And since I think you want to extract an hexadecimal number, you can simplify it more:

`(?i)J9VMTHREAD:(0x[0-9A-F]+)`

I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your pattern to be case insensitive as now it contains J9VMTHREAD and your input contains J9VMThread ( lower case):

```
Pattern lPattern = Pattern.compile("^.*THREADINFO.*\\sJ9VMTHREAD:([0123456789xABCDEF]*).*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```